# Why does my REST request to Kairos api say that the request is missing a required parameter?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I am trying to connect to the kairos api in order to become familiar with it and to use their detect function.

There is no official C# library for this api yet. There is one which does not seem to be actively maintained.

I am trying to connect directly using RestSharp. The server is receiving my request and responds like I expect it to if I leave out that app_id and app key for authentication. So that part (adding headers) seems to be working.

Adding parameters seems to be failing. According to their site: `https://www.kairos.com/docs/face-recognition/`the only required parameter is "image" with a url or base64 encoded photo.

I added the parameter:

```
var imageURL = new Uri("http://media.kairos.com/kairos-elizabeth.jpg");

        request.AddParameter("image", "{\"url\":\"" + imageURL + "\"}");
```

but the response is still:`"Error code: 1002",
"Message": One or more required parameters are missing.`

I suspect that there is an issue with how the uri is constructed but I really cannot put my finger on it. I copied the syntax

```
        request.AddParameter("image", "{\"url\":\"" + imageURL + "\"}");
```

from the same C# SDK I mentioned earlier.  I also tried it as simply:

```
var imageURL = new Uri("http://media.kairos.com/kairos-elizabeth.jpg");

        request.AddParameter("image", imageURL);
```

with no success.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
Just to be clear the full code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.kairos.com/");

        var request = new RestRequest("detect", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/JSON");
        request.AddHeader("app_id", "MY app ID");
        request.AddHeader("app_key", "My app KEY");

        var imageURL = new Uri("http://media.kairos.com/kairos-elizabeth.jpg");

        request.AddParameter("image", "\"url\":\"" + imageURL + "\"");
        request.AddParameter("selector:", "FACE");
        request.AddParameter("minHeadScale:", "0.125");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);


    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to serialize your parameters as JSON before sending it.

I created a dotnetfiddle to demonstrate this:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/VrKZo2

The documentation is not incorrect, you can pass just the `image` field and have it all work.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System;

    using RestSharp;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string appId = "YOUR APP ID HERE";
            string appKey = "YOUR APP KEY HERE";
            var client = new RestClient("https://api.kairos.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("detect", Method.POST);

            // automatically makes the request body serialize as JSON
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody(new { image = "http://media.kairos.com/kairos-elizabeth.jpg" });
            request.AddHeader("app_id", appId);
            request.AddHeader("app_key", appKey);

            var response = client.Execute(request);

            // handle response however you want, but I'm just going to print it out
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this with `appId` and `appKey` set, I get this content back:

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "time": 0.19603,
            "status": "Complete",
            "file": "face_55b7d7c4d2008.jpg",
            "width": 1536,
            "height": 2048,
            "faces": [
                {
                    "topLeftX": 300,
                    "topLeftY": 526,
                    "width": 934,
                    "height": 934,
                    "leftEyeCenterX": -1,
                    "leftEyeCenterY": -1,
                    "rightEyeCenterX": -1,
                    "rightEyeCenterY": -1,
                    "noseTipX": -1,
                    "noseTipY": -1,
                    "noseBtwEyesX": -1,
                    "noseBtwEyesY": -1,
                    "chinTipX": -1,
                    "chinTipY": -1,
                    "leftEyeCornerLeftX": -1,
                    "leftEyeCornerLeftY": -1,
                    "leftEyeCornerRightX": -1,
                    "leftEyeCornerRightY": -1,
                    "rightEyeCornerLeftX": -1,
                    "rightEyeCornerLeftY": -1,
                    "rightEyeCornerRightX": -1,
                    "rightEyeCornerRightY": -1,
                    "rightEarTragusX": -1,
                    "rightEarTragusY": -1,
                    "leftEarTragusX": -1,
                    "leftEarTragusY": -1,
                    "leftEyeBrowLeftX": -1,
                    "leftEyeBrowLeftY": -1,
                    "leftEyeBrowMiddleX": -1,
                    "leftEyeBrowMiddleY": -1,
                    "leftEyeBrowRightX": -1,
                    "leftEyeBrowRightY": -1,
                    "rightEyeBrowLeftX": -1,
                    "rightEyeBrowLeftY": -1,
                    "rightEyeBrowMiddleX": -1,
                    "rightEyeBrowMiddleY": -1,
                    "rightEyeBrowRightX": -1,
                    "rightEyeBrowRightY": -1,
                    "nostrilLeftHoleBottomX": -1,
                    "nostrilLeftHoleBottomY": -1,
                    "nostrilRightHoleBottomX": -1,
                    "nostrilRightHoleBottomY": -1,
                    "nostrilLeftSideX": -1,
                    "nostrilLeftSideY": -1,
                    "nostrilRightSideX": -1,
                    "nostrilRightSideY": -1,
                    "lipCornerLeftX": -1,
                    "lipCornerLeftY": -1,
                    "lipLineMiddleX": -1,
                    "lipLineMiddleY": -1,
                    "lipCornerRightX": -1,
                    "lipCornerRightY": -1,
                    "pitch": -1,
                    "yaw": -1,
                    "roll": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My program isn't just the 2 lines posted lol. I'm new here and the instructions were to post only what is absolutely necessary. my code actually looks basically exactly like your solution, which is how I was able to see the response. 
The response is still the same, that it's missing a required parameter.

Comment: @xerotolerant - I updated my post. Your problem was probably that you're not sending JSON over the wire. You'll see in my example that I do a `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json` and then pass the URL through `request.AddBody`. The `request.RequestFormat` means RestSharp will automatically serialize what you pass as JSON.

Comment: Thank you! You sir are awesome! It seemed to have been a combination of two things, which I would not have figured out on my own. I guess my syntax was wrong for the Json formatting. Also that AddBody thing. I am not really sure why it is is in Body and not header but you solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Argh, I had a trailing comma in the request with just the `image` parameter which coincidentally generated the same error! Removing my answer...